# How to obtain recursion relations from this

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to solve a problem using  the power series solution. Finally (and after substitution of differentations) I have come up with 
$$
-\frac1{2\mu}\sum_{i=2}^p i(i-1)a_i r^{(i-1)}+\frac1{2\mu}\omega \sum_{i=1}^p i\,a_i \,r^{(i+1)}-\frac{(l+1)}{\mu}\sum_{i=1}^p i\,a_i\,r^{(i-1)}-\frac{(4\mu^2-1)}{8\mu}\omega^2\sum_{i=0}^p a_i\,r^{(i+3)}+\frac{(2l+3)}{4\mu}\omega\sum_{i=0}^p a_i\,r^{i+1}-\sum_{i=0}^p a_i\,r^{i}=0
$$
According the power series solutions method now it's time to equalize the summation limits and powers of $r$, but here the powers include a variable called $l$. For this reason I'm confused how to proceed this calculation and get recursion relations?

**Addendum:**
As a user said there is no need to include $l$'s in the summations. So I divided out them. Now the problem is equalizing the powers and limits.

Comment: I will give it a shot , but could you possibly put a link for the original source of the question. So I can understand fully the question.

Comment: Please see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3193723/557780) however I have added a few constants to initial equation

Comment: For non zero $r$ you could try dividing out the common $r^l$ term. $l$ is not being summed over, so you can treat it as another coefficient

Comment: @user617446 Thanks a lot. However, I found that the problem is not $l$ but the differences between powers are the problem so that I can't treat this equation as standard power series solution problem (the powers differ 2 units there) since I don't know how to equalize the powers $i+l+3$ and $i+l$ for example.

Comment: Sorry, I was responding to "...but here the powers include a variable called l.For this reason I'm confused.. ". Once the messy $r^l$ terms are treated, you can try to look explicitly  at all the terms that start with $r^0,r^1, \cdots $ and I believe you will see how to continue.

Comment: @user617446 Thanks dear. I edited the question and removed $l$'s. So can you tell me how to proceed now?

Comment: Do you know how to handle a simple case? Say $\sum_{i=0}^p a_i r^i +\sum_{i=2}^p a_i r^i$ ?

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^p a_i r^i+\sum_{i=0}^p a_{i+2}r^i$ but what about 3 units differences?

Comment: The trick is to either write $\sum_{i=2}^p a_i r^i=\sum_{i=0}^p a_i r^i -a_0 -a_1 r^1$ or to write $\sum_{i=0}^p a_i r^i=\sum_{i=2}^p a_i r^i+a_0+a_1 r^1$